# Vim/NVim shows a weird character at cursor in terminal for comment lines

Tags: command-line, vim, cursor

I am using Ubuntu 23.04.

I don't have a custom .vimrc; I am using the system default.

EDIT: The following paragraph applies to only commented lines i.e. those beginning with a #. Non-commented lines don't have this issue.

When I open Vim/NVim on the tty terminal, the character at the block cursor in Normal mode (for a commented line) is weird e.g. the word "example" appears as "eGample" when the cursor is on the 'x'. Whitespace appears as 'I'.

This behavior disappears when I am in INSERT mode and the cursor changes to an underscore.

Also, when I use Vim/NVim from a terminal opened from a Desktop Environment (I am using KDE), then things work fine for all lines, commented or not.

What is wrong in the text terminal console for Vim? Please help!

Comment: What happens when you refresh the screen? Are you sure your $TERM environment variable is correct, and that your .vimrc term setting matches it?